# HTML form not sending data in Express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have the following form in HTML:

```
    <form method="post" id="registration-form" action="/register"> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UsernameRegistration">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UsernameRegistration">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PasswordRegistration">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordRegistration">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmPasswordRegistration">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPasswordRegistration">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" />
    </form>
```

The `/register` endpoints looks like the following:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
});
```

In req.query and req.body, there is no data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordRegistration">
```

Here the attribute **name** is not specified.
It should be like

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordRegistration">
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided name attribute for input elements .

I you provide name attribute to  element eg:

```
<form method="post" id="registration-form" action="/register"> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UsernameRegistration">Username:</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="UsernameRegistration">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PasswordRegistration">Password:</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="PasswordRegistration">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmPasswordRegistration">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input name="confpass" type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPasswordRegistration">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" />
    </form>

router.post("/registration", (req, res) => {
  var username = req.params.username;
  var  pass  = req.params.password;
  var confpass = req.params.confpass;
})
```

You will get data in req.params object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing these two things :-

1.Have you added **body parser** in our app ?? (Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser)

```
var app = require('express')();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

2. Missing **name** attribute in your form elements